# Setting A Variable With @Html.TextBox MVC3 ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, variables, webgrid

I'm working on a MVC3 ASP.Net application. I'm trying to figure out how to set the `Quantity` variable so when I pass it through to the controller with `Html.ActionLink` it has the correct number. Here's the view's code

```
@model IEnumerable<GreatVideosTrainingApplication.Models.Candy> 
@{
     ViewBag.Title = "Great Videos";
     List<GreatVideosTrainingApplication.Models.Candy> candies = new List<GreatVideosTrainingApplication.Models.Candy>();
     foreach (var candy in Model)
     {
        candies.Add(candy);
     }
     var grid = new WebGrid(candies);
     var Quantity = 0;
}
<p>Welcome To Great Videos! The best source for your favorite DVDs and Blu-Rays</p>
<img src ="/Content/Images/dvd50.jpg" />
<p></p>
<img src="/Content/Images/bluray.jpg" />
<form method="post" action="/ShoppingCart/AddToCandyCart/"+item.CandyID >

 @grid.GetHtml(@columns: grid.Columns(
                                grid.Column("Name"),
                                grid.Column("Price"),
                                grid.Column("Quantity", format: (item) =>  @Html.TextBox("Quantity", @Quantity)),
                                grid.Column("AddToCart", format: (item) => Html.ActionLink("Add To Cart", "AddToCandyCart", "ShoppingCart", new { id = item.CandyID, quantity = @Quantity }, ""))
                    )
)

 </form>
```

I'm trying to set the value for the quantity with the `Html.TextBox` but it's not working. Keep in mind here I don't know javascript, and I'm extremely new to MVC3. Any and all help is greatly appreciated though.

```
    public ActionResult AddToCandyCart(int id, FormCollection values)
    {
        // Add it to the shopping cart
        var quantity = values["Quantity"];
        var cart = ShoppingCart.GetCart(this.HttpContext);
        // Retrieve the video from the database
        var addedCandy = storeDB.Candies.Single(Candy => Candy.CandyID == id);
        cart.AddToCandyCart(addedCandy, int.Parse(quantity));
        // Go back to the main store page for more shopping
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

Comment: Did you tried setting the value like this: grid.Column("Quantity", format: (item) => Html.TextBox("Quantity", (int)item.Quantity)) ... that should do the trick (not tested)

Comment: Please, could you provide the action code? Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps you should first check out any [MVC3 tutorial](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc3/cs/accessing-your-model's-data-from-a-controller). Try to learn the basic patterns and practices, without those basic guidelines MVC gets really hard to use. What we need is the `HttpGet` ActionResult, so we can checkout the model and see, for example, if it's being correctly managed. For expample, if Quantity prop is Nullable, then you might need to cast it to `Nullable<int>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code worked for me when including a textbox. I had trouble with the html helpers so I just wrote the code for the input box directly. I hope this helps.

```
grid.Column("Quantity", format: @<text><input name="Quantity" type="text" value="@item.Quantity"</text>))
```

Comment: Doing that keeps giving me an error: Error 9 Argument 3: cannot convert from 'lambda expression' to 'System.Func<dynamic,object>'

Answer (score 1):

Figured out the problem from mixing a variety of sources. Wanted to thank everyone. Here's the view.

```
@model IEnumerable<GreatVideosTrainingApplication.Models.Candy> 
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Great Videos";
    List<GreatVideosTrainingApplication.Models.Candy> candies = new List<GreatVideosTrainingApplication.Models.Candy>();
    foreach (var candy in Model)
    {
        candies.Add(candy);
    }
    var grid = new WebGrid(candies);
    var Quantity = 0;
}

<p>Welcome To Great Videos! The best source for your favorite DVDs and Blu-Rays</p>
<img src ="/Content/Images/dvd50.jpg" />
<p></p>
<img src="/Content/Images/bluray.jpg" />
<form method="post" action="../ShoppingCart/AddToCandyCart/" >
    @using (Html.BeginForm()) { 
        @grid.GetHtml(@columns: grid.Columns(
                                        grid.Column("Name"),
                                        grid.Column("Price"),
                                        grid.Column("Quantity", format: @<text><input name="Quantity" type="text" value="@Quantity"</text>),
                                        grid.Column("AddToCart", format: @<text><input type="submit" value="Add To Cart" name="submit" /></text>)
                            )
    )
}
</form>
```

Here's the Action Controller

```
 [HttpPost]
 public ActionResult AddToCandyCart(FormCollection values)
 {
        int id = 1;
        string[] quantities = values["Quantity"].Split(','); 
        foreach (var item in quantities)
        {
            try
            {
                int quantity = int.Parse(item);
                if (quantity >= 1)
                {
                    // Add the candy to the shopping cart
                    var addedCandy = storeDB.Candies.Single(Candy => Candy.CandyID == id);
                    var cart = ShoppingCart.GetCart(this.HttpContext);
                    cart.AddToCandyCart(addedCandy, int.Parse(item));
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                return View("Failed");
            }

            id++;
        }
        // Go back to the main store page for more shopping
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
 }
```